# Is it possible to pass cursors with parameter as a parameter of a procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got a lot of similar treatments to do and I want to make a pl/sql script for it.
It's easier to understand by looking code rather than explain it so here it is a simplify version :

```
create or replace package my_test as
  cursor my_cursor(my_filter NUMBER) is select column1, column2 from mytable where column3 = my_filter;
  cursor my_cursor2(my_filter VARCHAR2) is select column1, column2 from mytable where column4 LIKE my_filter;
  -- ...

  procedure test1;
  procedure test2(p_cursor XXX);
  function test3(test_record XXX%ROWTYPE) return number;

end my_test;
/

create or replace package body my_test as
  procedure test1 is    
  begin
    test2(my_cursor(3));
    test2(my_cursor2('foo%'));
    test2(my_cursor(5));
    -- ...
  end test1;

  procedure test2(p_cursor XXX) is
    tmp number;
  begin
    for r in p_cursor loop      
      --some actions 
      tmp := test3(r);
      --some actions
    end loop;
  end test2;

  function test3(test_record XXX%ROWTYPE) return number is
    tmp_sum number;
  begin
    -- ...
    tmp_sum := test_record.column1 + test_record.column2;
    -- ...
    return l_summ;
  end test3;


end my_test;
/

BEGIN
    my_test.test1();
END;
/
```

I've tried my best but didn't succeed. Maybe someone can help me ? It is possible to achieve such a thing ? What should I put instead of `XXX` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a record type to match the projection of the queries you want to execute. You can use this to define the IN parameter of `test3()`.

Define a ref cursor which returns this record type. You can use this to define the IN parameter of `test2()`.

Instead of cursors define functions which return ref cursors, defined by that cursor type.

So your package looks like this:

```
create or replace package my_test as

  type t_record is record(
     column1 mytable.column1%type
    ,column2 mytable.column2%type
  );

  type t_cursor is ref cursor return t_record;

  function my_cursor (my_filter NUMBER)   return t_cursor ;
  function my_cursor2(my_filter VARCHAR2) return t_cursor ;

  procedure test1;
  procedure test2(p_cursor t_cursor);
  function  test3(test_record t_record) return number;

end my_test;
/
```

and the implementation looks like this (with some output to make the demo more intelligible):

```
create or replace package body my_test as

  function my_cursor(my_filter NUMBER) return t_cursor is 
      rc sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open rc for  select column1, column2 from mytable where column3 = my_filter;
    return rc;
  end my_cursor;

  function my_cursor2(my_filter VARCHAR2)  return t_cursor is 
      rc sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open rc for  select column1, column2 from mytable where column4 LIKE my_filter;
    return rc;
  end my_cursor2;

  procedure test1 is    
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('test2(my_cursor, 3)');
    test2(my_cursor(3)); 
    dbms_output.put_line('test2(my_cursor2, foo');
    test2(my_cursor2('foo%'));
    dbms_output.put_line('test2(my_cursor,5)');
    test2(my_cursor(5));
    -- ...
  end test1;

  procedure test2(p_cursor t_cursor) is
    tmp number;
    l_rec t_record;
  begin
    loop
      fetch p_cursor into l_rec;
      exit when p_cursor%notfound;
      --some actions 
      tmp := test3(l_rec);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.column1 ||'+'||l_rec.column2||'='||tmp);
      --some actions
    end loop;
    close p_cursor;
  end test2;

  function test3(test_record t_record) return number is
    tmp_sum number;
  begin
    -- ...
    tmp_sum := test_record.column1 + test_record.column2;
    -- ...
    return tmp_sum;
  end test3;

end my_test;
/
```

Did I say demo? Of course there's [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72cda88cf3ea3abc9404f2210f16c534).

Comment: Not only a (really) quick response but also with a demo. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Cursor variables are a perfect fit for what you want to do!

Here's a rewrite of a portion of your code illustrating how to use them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_test
AS
   PROCEDURE test1;

   PROCEDURE test2 (p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END my_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_test
AS
   FUNCTION my_cursor (my_filter NUMBER)
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   IS
      l_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
      OPEN l_cursor FOR
         SELECT column1, column2
           FROM mytable
          WHERE column3 = my_filter;

      RETURN l_cursor;
   END;

   PROCEDURE test1
   IS
   BEGIN
      test2 (my_cursor (3));
      test2 (my_cursor (5));
   END test1;

   PROCEDURE test2 (p_cursor xxx)
   IS
      tmp   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      LOOP
         FETCH p_cursor INTO tmp;

         EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;
         --some actions
         NULL;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE p_cursor;
   END test2;
END my_test;
/
```

You use OPEN FOR syntax to associate a query (and its result set) with a variable. You can then use the usual operations FETCH, CLOSE, references to %cursor attributes.

AND close the cursor when you are done. :-)